# Python Paramiko - Run command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm try to run this script:

```
hostname = '192.168.3.4'
port = 22
username = 'username'
password = 'mypassword'
y = "2012"
m = "02"
d = "27"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   s = paramiko.SSHClient()
   s.load_system_host_keys()
   s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
   command = 'ls /home/user/images/cappi/03000/y/m/d'
   s.close
```

The question is:
how can I put the variables `y`,`m`,`d` into the variable `command` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python has lots of ways to perform string formatting.  One of the simplest is to simply concatenate the parts of your string together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko

hostname = "192.168.3.4"
port = 22
username = "username"
password = "mypassword"
y = "2012"
m = "02"
d = "27"

def do_it():
    s = paramiko.SSHClient()
    s.load_system_host_keys()
    s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
    command = "ls /home/user/images/cappi/03000/" + y + "/" + m + "/" + d
    stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command(command)
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        print line
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_it()
```

Comment: I don't see that that's significantly better.  Now if you had said '/'.join([y, m, d]) you'd have a case.

Comment: The problem here is not syntax, the problem is that if you run `a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + an`, you're creating and destroying `n-1` temporary strings. `join` in Python only creates 1 string. This is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: I would point out 1. n is very small here, 2. the + operator is very readable here, and 3. http://greaterdebater.com/blog/gabe/post/7

Comment: @matt: I think we're going to have to agree to disagree here. This is a convention, and getting in the habit of doing it properly is best, IMO.

Comment: Using the plus sign for string concatenation is the most un-Pythonic way to do it. Python has like 4 ways to format stings. Percent encoding, f strings, .format, and templates are all preferred over the plus sign. ALSO escape terminal input. pipes.quote is there for a reason.

Comment: This answer is generally correct. But the code is not reliable. It can deadlock in some scenarios. For details, see [Wait to finish command executed with Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34181078/850848#66839039).

Answer (score 3):

```
command = 'ls /home/user/images/cappi/03000/%s/%s/%s' %(y,m,d)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [new format specifications](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples), you can access arguments by name:

```
'ls /home/user/images/cappi/03000/{year}/{month}/{day}'.format(year=y, month=m, day=d)
```

Comment: You need to put an f in front of the string.

Comment: @kagronick [since Python 3.6 you can use f-strings (PEP 498)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), but the above `.format(...)` string is perfectly valid [since Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and in [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Oh I didn't scroll to the right on my phone. .format was new in 2006 so I assumed f strings were what you were talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer

```
command = f"ls /home/user/images/cappi/03000/{y}/{m}/{d}"
```