# SSH with Python Script

Tags: python, ssh, putty

I'm new at python and i'm trying to create a Python script to SSH (Throw putty), to my server and to execute 'sudo reboot' command (as you probbebly know , sudo is a requied a pass).

as I search here and google, I found this:
[Python script for SSH through PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598361/python-script-for-ssh-through-putty?rq=1)

At Putty download page there is 'Plink' I've downloaded that (few version tbh) and it's just open it and close it , not installing something or showme anything. just closing the window soon it's opened.
What am I missing?
also tried to do that with Paramiko:

```
import paramiko

host = "myip"
port = 22
username = "myusername"
password = "mypassword"

command = "sudo reboot"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
ssh.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: why use putty? use paramiko - http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html

Comment: I've tried that as well, with that: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-ssh-using-paramiko-in-python
i've installed it and it's not really working and I don't know how to add a command to execute.

Comment: No one will be able to help  if you are not sharing the code. So share the code that calls paramiko.

Comment: I've editted the thread, thank you.

Comment: what happen when you run the code? Please attache all error details (if there is one)

Comment: No error, but the command is not execute.

Comment: can you  communicate with this server (as human) via putty or other ssh client?

Comment: Yes , Via Putty I can log in and execute by myself the command, if this what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with executing commands, you need to read their (error) output to see any error messages.

- Also your current code does not even complete the command. And *reading the command output* is the actually easiest way in Paramiko to actually get your command *completed*.

  See [Wait to finish command executed with Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34181078/850848#66839039)
- For another common problem, see [Some Unix commands fail with "<command> not found", when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55419330/850848)