# Execute command and wait for it to finish with Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I wrote this code in Paramiko:

```
ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, username=user, password=passwd, timeout=3)

session = ssh.invoke_shell()
session.send("\n")

session.send("echo step 1\n")
time.sleep(1)

session.send("sleep 30\n")
time.sleep(1)

while not session.recv_ready():
    time.wait(2)

output = session.recv(65535)

session.send("echo step 2\n")
time.sleep(1)

output += session.recv(65535)
```

I'm trying execute more commands on my Linux server. The problem is my Python code not wait to finish execute command, for example if I'm try to execute `sleep 30`, the Python not wait 30 seconds for finish execute commands. How can resolve this problem ? I tried with `while recv_ready()`, but it still does not wait.

Answer (score 11):

Use `exec_command`: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/channel.html

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("my_long_command --arg 1 --arg 2")
```

The following code works for me:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy
import time
ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('111.111.111.111', username='myname', key_filename='/path/to/my/id_rsa.pub', port=1123)
sleeptime = 0.001
outdata, errdata = '', ''
ssh_transp = ssh.get_transport()
chan = ssh_transp.open_session()
# chan.settimeout(3 * 60 * 60)
chan.setblocking(0)
chan.exec_command('ls -la')
while True:  # monitoring process
    # Reading from output streams
    while chan.recv_ready():
        outdata += chan.recv(1000)
    while chan.recv_stderr_ready():
        errdata += chan.recv_stderr(1000)
    if chan.exit_status_ready():  # If completed
        break
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
retcode = chan.recv_exit_status()
ssh_transp.close()

print(outdata)
print(errdata)
```

Please note that command `history` cannot be executed with ssh as is.
See example here: https://superuser.com/questions/962001/incorrect-output-of-history-command-of-ssh-how-to-read-the-timestamp-info-corre

Comment: i need use invoke_shell because whit exec_command not return output complete

Comment: This code can indeed lose some output. You need to test the `exit_status_ready` before reading (but exit only after reading). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/66191219/850848. Though see my answer for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

In case you do not need to read the stdout and stderr separately, you can use way more straightforward code:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
stdout.channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
output = stdout.readlines()
```

The `readlines` reads until the command finishes and returns a complete output.

---

In case you need the output separately, do not be tempted to remove the `set_combine_stderr` and call `readlines` on `stdout` and `stderr` separately. That might deadlock. See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848)

For a correct code that reads the outputs separately, see [Run multiple commands in different SSH servers in parallel using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66191219/850848).

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.