# Paramiko authentication fails with "Agreed upon 'rsa-sha2-512' pubkey algorithm" (and "unsupported public key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512" in sshd log)

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I have a Python 3 application running on CentOS Linux 7.7 executing SSH commands against remote hosts. It works properly but today I encountered an odd error executing a command against a "new" remote server (server based on RHEL 6.10):

> encountered RSA key, expected OPENSSH key

Executing the same command from the system shell (using the same private key of course) works perfectly fine.

On the remote server I discovered in `/var/log/secure` that when SSH connection and commands are issued from the source server with Python (using Paramiko) sshd complains about unsupported public key algorithm:

> userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512

Note that target servers with higher RHEL/CentOS like 7.x don't encounter the issue.

It seems like Paramiko picks/offers the wrong algorithm when negotiating with the remote server when on the contrary SSH shell performs the negotiation properly in the context of this "old" target server. How to get the Python program to work as expected?

**Python code**

```
import paramiko
import logging

ssh_user = "my_user"
ssh_keypath = "/path/to/.ssh/my_key.rsa"
server = "server.tld"

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 
ssh_client.connect(server,port=22,username=ssh_user, key_filename=ssh_keypath)  

# SSH command
cmd = "echo TEST : $(hostname)"

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True)
exit_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() 

cmd_raw_output = stdout.readlines()
out = "".join(cmd_raw_output)
out_msg = out.strip()  

# Ouput (logger code omitted)
logger.debug(out_msg)

if ssh_client is not None:
    ssh_client.close()
```

**Shell command equivalent**

```
ssh -i /path/to/.ssh/my_key.rsa my_user@server.tld "echo TEST : $(hostname)"
```

**Paramiko logs (DEBUG)**

```
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.475] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0xf6054ac8
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.476] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.9.1
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.490] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
INF [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.490] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.3)
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.498] thr=1   paramiko.transport: === Key exchange possibilities ===
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.498] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.498] thr=1   paramiko.transport: server key: ssh-rsa, ssh-dss
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.498] thr=1   paramiko.transport: client encrypt: aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, arcfour256, arcfour128, aes128-cbc, 3des-cbc, blowfish-cbc, cast128-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes256-cbc, arcfour, rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.498] thr=1   paramiko.transport: server encrypt: aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, arcfour256, arcfour128, aes128-cbc, 3des-cbc, blowfish-cbc, cast128-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes256-cbc, arcfour, rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.499] thr=1   paramiko.transport: client mac: hmac-md5, hmac-sha1, umac-64@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-ripemd160, hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-96, hmac-md5-96
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.499] thr=1   paramiko.transport: server mac: hmac-md5, hmac-sha1, umac-64@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-ripemd160, hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-96, hmac-md5-96
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.499] thr=1   paramiko.transport: client compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.499] thr=1   paramiko.transport: server compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.499] thr=1   paramiko.transport: client lang: <none>
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.499] thr=1   paramiko.transport: server lang: <none>.
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.499] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex follows: False
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.500] thr=1   paramiko.transport: === Key exchange agreements ===
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.500] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.500] thr=1   paramiko.transport: HostKey: ssh-rsa
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.500] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher: aes128-ctr
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.500] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC: hmac-sha2-256
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.501] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression: none
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.501] thr=1   paramiko.transport: === End of kex handshake ===
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.548] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Got server p (2048 bits)
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.666] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexGexSHA256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.667] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.669] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-rsa host key for server.tld: b'caea********************.'
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.674] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying discovered key b'b49c********************' in /path/to/.ssh/my_key.rsa
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.722] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.722] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Finalizing pubkey algorithm for key of type 'ssh-rsa'
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.722] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Our pubkey algorithm list: ['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa']
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.723] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Server-side algorithm list: ['']
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.723] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Agreed upon 'rsa-sha2-512' pubkey algorithm
INF [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.735] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.739] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying SSH agent key b'9d37********************'
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.747] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK.
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.748] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Finalizing pubkey algorithm for key of type 'ssh-rsa'
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.748] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Our pubkey algorithm list: ['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa']
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.748] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Server-side algorithm list: ['']
DEB [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.748] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Agreed upon 'rsa-sha2-512' pubkey algorithm
INF [YYYYmmdd-HH:MM:30.868] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed...
```

**Shell command logs**

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "server.tld" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server.tld [server.tld] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /path/to/.ssh/my_key.rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /path/to/.ssh/my_key.rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to server.tld:22 as 'my_user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/path/to/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /path/to/.ssh/known_hosts:82
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from server.tld
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1502/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-.:**************************************************
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/path/to/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /path/to/.ssh/known_hosts:8..2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from server.tld
debug1: Host 'server.tld' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /path/to/.ssh/known_hosts:82
debug2: bits set: 1562/3072
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: <foo> (0x55bcf6d1d320), agent
debug2: key: /path/to/.ssh/my_key.rsa ((nil)), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: <foo>
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /path/to/.ssh/my_key.rsa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:**********************************
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server.tld ([server.tld]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env CDPATH
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = xx_XX.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: echo TEST : $(hostname)
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
TEST : server.tld
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Transferred: sent 3264, received 2656 bytes, in 0.0 seconds.
Bytes per second: sent 92349.8, received 75147.4
debug1: Exit status 0
.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Imo, it's a bug in Paramiko. It does not handle correctly absence of `server-sig-algs` extension on the server side.

Try disabling `rsa-sha2-*` on Paramiko side altogether:

```
ssh_client.connect(
  server, username=ssh_user, key_filename=ssh_keypath,
  disabled_algorithms=dict(pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512", "rsa-sha2-256"]))
```

*(note that there's no need to specify `port=22`, as that's the default)*

I've found related Paramiko issue:
[RSA key auth failing from paramiko 2.9.x client to dropbear server](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1961)

Though it refers to [Paramiko 2.9.0 change log](https://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html#2.9.0), which seems to imply that the behavior is deliberate:

> When the server does not send `server-sig-algs`, Paramiko will attempt the first algorithm in the above list. Clients connecting to legacy servers should thus use `disabled_algorithms` to turn off SHA2.

---

Since [2.9.2](https://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html#2.9.2), Paramiko will say:

> DEB [20220113-14:46:13.882] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Server did not send a server-sig-algs list; defaulting to our first preferred algo ('rsa-sha2-512')
> DEB [20220113-14:46:13.882] thr=1   paramiko.transport: NOTE: you may use the 'disabled_algorithms' SSHClient/Transport init kwarg to disable that or other algorithms if your server does not support them!

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

---

*Your code for waiting for command to complete and reading its output is flawed too. See [Wait to finish command executed with Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34181078/850848#66839039). And for most purposes, the `get_pty=True` is not a good idea either.*

Comment: It turn out that 'rsa-sha2-256' was also needed in the disabled_algorithms list. Thanks for your detailled answer & advices on AutoAddPolicy/reading command output/get_pty

Comment: This saved us after several hours of debugging. Your syntax for disabled_algorithms does NOT match paramiko documentation but it works, i.e. disabled_algorithms=dict(pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512", "rsa-sha2-256"])). 
From paramiko (https://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html): "Specifically, you need to specify disabled_algorithms={'keys': ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512']} in either SSHClient or Transport. See below for details on why."

Comment: For me, disabling "keys" (as suggested in paramiko's changelog) did not work, only after I disabled "pubkeys" I was able to connect. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: You saved us big time! Thanks a looooooooot <3

Answer (score 2):

Its a known RSA Auth issue of paramiko.

If you do not want to jump into the complexities of implementing paramiko changes. Try downgrading to 2.8.1 version of paramiko and it should solve your problem in a blink.
**To install paramiko 2.8.1 :**

```
 pip install 'paramiko<=2.8.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed one issue but caused another with other servers which only use the disabled algorithms. The following resulted in "Unable to agree on a pubkey algorithm for signing a ssh-rsa" happens

```
DISABLED_ALGORITHMS = {'keys': ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512'], 'pubkeys':['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256']}
```

So I ended up moving ssh-rsa up in the preferred list which allows post 2.9.0+ to default to ssh-rsa when no server-sig-algs is returned. "Server did not send a server-sig-algs list"

```
from packaging import version
if version.parse(paramiko.__version__) > version.parse("2.8.1") and version.parse(paramiko.__version__) <= version.parse("2.12.0"):
    print(f"Paramiko Version:{paramiko.__version__}")
    _preferred_pubkeys = (
    "ssh-ed25519",
    "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256",
    "ecdsa-sha2-nistp384",
    "ecdsa-sha2-nistp521",
    "ssh-rsa",
    "rsa-sha2-512",
    "rsa-sha2-256",
    "ssh-dss",
    )
    
    print(f"Patching _preferred_pubkeys {paramiko.transport.Transport._preferred_pubkeys} with {_preferred_pubkeys}")
    paramiko.transport.Transport._preferred_pubkeys = _preferred_pubkeys
```

Comment: Thank you, useful idea. I phrased it a bit differently (wanted to reply here but faced comment length limit, so post as another answer).

Answer (score 1):

Hello after adding this:

```
ssh_client.connect(
  server, username=ssh_user, key_filename=ssh_keypath,
  disabled_algorithms=dict(pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512", "rsa-sha2-256"]))
```

I got the following error:

```
Our pubkey algorithm list: ['ssh-rsa']
Server did not send a server-sig-algs list; defaulting to our first preferred algo ('ssh-rsa')
NOTE: you may use the 'disabled_algorithms' SSHClient/Transport init kwarg to disable that or other algorithms if your server does not support them!
```

I fixed it by adding the following:

```
 client.connect(hostname=self.hostname_sfp,
                           username=self.user_sftp,
                           password=self.password_sftp,
                           port=self.port_sftp,
                           disabled_algorithms=dict(pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512", "rsa-sha2-256"]),
                           allow_agent=False,
                           look_for_keys=False
                           )
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem. You switched to password authentication, which is simply unacceptable in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly differently formulated idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74349827/48167
(it is very useful in case paramiko is not used directly but used by library used by library I use, so configuring paramiko directly turns out to be difficult ;-))

I rewrote it to „be safer” – instead of blindly overwriting list of key types, I just reorganize the list I found, by moving any rsa-sha2-… items down behind ssh-rsa:

```
import paramiko.transport
if hasattr(paramiko.transport.Transport, '_preferred_pubkeys'):
    pk = paramiko.transport.Transport._preferred_pubkeys
    ssh_rsa_pos = pk.index('ssh-rsa')
    if ssh_rsa_pos >= 0:
        fixed_pk = [
            x for x in pk[:ssh_rsa_pos]
            if not x.startswith('rsa-sha2-')
        ] + [
            pk[ssh_rsa_pos]
        ] + [
            x for x in pk[:ssh_rsa_pos]
            if x.startswith('rsa-sha2-')
        ] + list(pk[ssh_rsa_pos + 1:])
        paramiko.transport.Transport._preferred_pubkeys = tuple(fixed_pk)
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up with the following code to avoid disabling these algorithms for other connections. We have an Airflow environment in which hundreds of DAGs are using a common Operator)

```
try:
    ssh.connect(ip, **args)
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
    ssh.connect(ip, 
                disabled_algorithms=dict(keys=['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512'],
                                         pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512","rsa-sha2-256"]), 
                **args)
```

**Edit**: please read the comment by @Martin Prikryl regarding the security concerns of using this method.

Comment: This is only seemingly better solution. With this code, an MITM attacker can easily make you use obsolete algorithms.

Comment: Good call Martin. This should be only used with caution. Our code base connects only to known servers. But definitely needs to be taken into account