# Paramiko is giving PasswordRequiredException error for SSH Key authentication

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

Code:

```py
pkey=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(key_path)
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host, username='xxxxx',pkey=pkey)
```

I didn't set any passphrase to the private key. So, I not passing any argument for it.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 435, in connect
    self._auth(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 766, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 736, in _auth
    key = self._key_from_filepath(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 588, in _key_from_filepath
    key = klass.from_private_key_file(key_path, password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 249, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 64, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 194, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 322, in _read_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key(tag, f, password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 351, in _read_private_key
    data = self._read_private_key_openssh(lines[start:end], password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 452, in _read_private_key_openssh
    raise PasswordRequiredException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: private key file is encrypted
```

I could able to connect successfully using FileZilla and also SSH.
SSH verbose output

```
ssh -v -i /Users/aptuz/Downloads/integra_rsa user@host  
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6  
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/aptuz/.ssh/config  
debug1: /Users/aptuz/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *   
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *  
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling  
debug1: Connecting to host port 22.  
debug1: Connection established.  
debug1: identity file /Users/aptuz/Downloads/integra_rsa type 0  
debug1: identity file /Users/aptuz/Downloads/integra_rsa-cert type -1  
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6  
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GXSSSHD_Comments  
debug1: compat_banner: no match: GXSSSHD_Comments  
debug1: Authenticating to host:22 as 'user'  
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/aptuz/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory  
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory  
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received  
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256  
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa  
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none  
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received  
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:9spuefLNoQEYjtHhNfF3Emwbnlqibxbam2QYf5VXEp4  
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/aptuz/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory  
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory  
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory  
debug1: Host 'host' is known and matches the RSA host key.  
debug1: Found key in /Users/aptuz/.ssh/known_hosts:10  
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received  
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks  
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/aptuz/Downloads/integra_rsa RSA     SHA256:A8qNBO5MTleOBw3oRxo09zj5iiLpG6Tl8u0iHnG+7W0 explicit  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received  
Please login with user ID and password.debug1: Authentications that can continue:   password,publickey,keyboard-interactive  
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey  
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/aptuz/Downloads/integra_rsa RSA   SHA256:A8qNBO5MTleOBw3oRxo09zj5iiLpG6Tl8u0iHnG+7W0 explicit  
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/aptuz/Downloads/integra_rsa RSA   SHA256:A8qNBO5MTleOBw3oRxo09zj5iiLpG6Tl8u0iHnG+7W0 explicit  
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).  
Authenticated to host ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).  
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]  
debug1: Entering interactive session.  
debug1: pledge: filesystem full  
debug1: Sending environment.  
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"  
This server does not support an interactive session.  
Goodbye.  
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1  
Connection to host closed.  
Transferred: sent 3688, received 2716 bytes, in 1.6 seconds  
Bytes per second: sent 2302.4, received 1695.6  
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace, you can see that the error does not come from your `RSAKey.from_private_key_file`, but rather from somewhere deep in `SSHClient.connect`.

That likely means that the authentication with `key_path` failed and Paramiko resorted to try the default keys in `.ssh` folder (due to the default `look_for_keys=True` argument of `SSHClient.connect`). You probably have an encrypted key there. Failing to load it, hides away your presumed *"Authentication failed"* problem.

Check Paramiko log file for details. You might have this problem:
[Paramiko authentication fails with "Agreed upon 'rsa-sha2-512' pubkey algorithm" (and "unsupported public key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512" in sshd log)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70565357/850848)