# PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Is there a way to have the same behavior with Paramiko, as when using `ssh` option:

```
-o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paramiko uses `ssh-rsa` by default. No need to enable it.

But if you have problems with public keys, it might be because recent versions of Paramiko first try `rsa-sha2-*`. And some legacy servers choke on that. So you likely rather want to disable the `rsa-sha2-*`.

For that, see:
[Paramiko authentication fails with "Agreed upon 'rsa-sha2-512' pubkey algorithm" (and "unsupported public key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512" in sshd log)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70565357/850848)