# Paramiko exec_command fails with 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I'm new to Paramiko. I am attempting to create a simple script that allows anyone to use their Linux credentials to run the command. I decided to test with a simple `ls` command but I am receiving errors.

```
import paramiko
username = *<USERNAME>*
hostname = *<HOSTNAME>*
port = 22
trans = paramiko.Transport((hostname,port))
trans.connect(username=username, password=password)
channel = trans.open_channel("session")
print(channel.send_ready())
print(channel.get_transport())
stdin,stdout,stderr = channel.exec_command("ls -lah")
trans.close()
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-ce837beea6fe> in <module>()
      6 trans.connect(username=username, password=password)
      7 channel = trans.open_channel("session")
----> 8 stdin,stdout,stderr = channel.exec_command("ls -lah")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any Ideas as to what I might be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's no `session` channel in SSH (unless your server has some non-standard channels implemented). There are `sftp`, `shell` and `exec` channels.

   You want to use `exec` channel.
2. And you do not need to open `exec` channel explicitly in Paramiko. Just use [`SSHClient.exec_command` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command).

   `SSHClient.exec_command` (contrary to `Channel.exec_command`) returns 3-touple.

See for example [Python Paramiko - Run command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9470584/850848):

```
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.load_system_host_keys()
s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
command = 'ls -lah'
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = s.exec_command(command)
```