# Difference between exec_command in client and channel of Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

In Python package Paramiko, there exists `exec_command` method in `channel.py` and `client.py`, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Channel`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html) is a low-level API that you should not use in general.

The [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) calls [`Channel.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.exec_command) and after that creates `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` objects and returns them as 3-touple. With `Channel` you would have to create these objects yourself (as without them the `Channel.exec_command` is useless).

See also [Paramiko exec_command fails with 'NoneType' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51103887/850848).

Additionally, the `SSHClient.exec_command` has `get_pty` and `environment` parameters that trigger [`Channel.get_pty()`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.get_pty) and [`Channel.update_environment`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.update_environment) respectively.

Check [`SSHClient.exec_command` source code](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/3.3.1/paramiko/client.py#L520).