# Opening SSH session and running commands in different terminal in Python

Tags: python, mysql

Below is the process I am doing manually and I want to automate it in Python.

1. I am opening SSH terminal to MySQL server using below command

```
cf ssh -L 63380:100.120.11.22:3380 appname
```

2. Once this SSH is established I am doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a new terminal tab and run below command to create DB objects

```
mysql -u myuser -h 0 -pmypassword -D mydbname -P 3380 < init_db/mysql/schema.ddl
```

Now I have written Python code for step 1 like below

```
process = subprocess.Popen("cf ssh -L 63380:100.120.11.22:3380 appname",shell = True)
```

It opens SSH terminal but when ran second step using below code it does not connect to opened SSH terminal it says not able to connect to MySQL server.

```
pro = subprocess.Popen("mysql -u myuser -h 0 -pmypassword -D mydbname -P 3380 < init_db/mysql/schema.ddl", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

I have searched and tried other options like writing step 2 in different program and calling from first program after SSH is established but of no use.

Kindly let me know if any solution is available in Python for this.
Env: mac, pcf.

Comment: You shold take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470584/python-paramiko-run-command)

Comment: My query is bit different. I have looked at the previous problems raised and most of them are related to open ssh terminal and run commands in that terminal but my problem is I need to open different terminal to run a command.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you need to automate interacting with the UI too?

Comment: No, just open ssh terminal and run command in different terminal.

Comment: So your command doesn't need to be run over the ssh connection?

Comment: Not the opened terminal(SSH) but in another terminal it will connect to opened terminal and run command

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this command:

```
cf ssh -L 63380:100.120.11.22:3380 appname
```

ssh's to your CloudFoundry application server and forwards any connection on your local machine's port 63380 to the remote port 3380. So it seems like your mysql connection should be:

```
mysql -u myuser -h localhost -pmypassword -D mydbname -P 63380 < init_db/mysql/schema.ddl
```

where `init_db/mysql/schema.ddl` is on your local machine.

I'm not completely sure if this will work with CloudFoundry, but with ssh you can run a remote command like this:

```
ssh username@<host or ip> <command>
#for example:
ssh myname@example.com ls -al
```

So you might try putting `~/init_db/mysql/schema.dll` on the server and use this command:

```
cf ssh appname mysql -u myuser -pmypassword -Dmydbname -P 3380 < ~/init_db/mysql/schema.dll
```

You should be able to drop that command into python's `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: Thank you for looking at the issue. But it is not working. First I need to open ssh and then in second command I need to fire mysql command. I can not combine both into one. Atleast in case of CF it is not working. More details of steps can found here. https://github.com/pivotal-cf/PivotalMySQLWeb. I want to achieve this in python.

Comment: I have not tried to do ls -al but to run mysql command and it did not work.

Comment: If you can run `cf ssh myapp ls -al` then you can find a mysql command that will work.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are suggesting to run only one command or two commands? If two commands then problem remains the same. If I run ssh command and then inside ssh I will not find mysql client.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is you should be able to run a command over ssh on the remote server. Is the database on the server, or on your local machine?

Comment: Database is again a pcf service. We connect to that service from local machine to import ddl script.

Answer (score 0):

I found way of avoiding the ssh to mysql. There is a cf mysql plugin by which we can connect to cf mysql services and execute the queries.
More details can be found at:
https://github.com/andreasf/cf-mysql-plugin