# Paramiko with Juniper echos commands executed

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, juniper, juniper-network-connect

When getting an o/p from Juniper using Paramiko, the output first shows the commands and then execute the commands. Below is the code and output

```
import paramiko
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
with open('ips.txt','r') as f:      
    ip = f.read().splitlines()
for device in ip:
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(device, port=22, username='test', password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
    remote_connection.send('set cli screen-length 500\n')
    remote_connection.send('ping 4.2.2.2 rapid\n')
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    output = remote_connection.recv(4096)
    print(output.decode())
    with open('Backup.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write(output)
        f.write("\n********************\n")
    ssh_client.close()
```

Output is below:

```
Password: 
--- JUNOS  XXX built XXX
set cli screen-length 500 <---- Is it something relevant with Juniper when running python with paramiko. 
ping 4.2.2.2 rapid <-----
{master:0}
XXX> set cli screen-length 500 
Screen length set to 500

{master:0}
XXX> ping 4.2.2.2 rapid
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2): 56 data bytes
!!!!!
--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 43.876/52.403/55.517/4.345 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the commands by simulating typing them on an interactive shell terminal interface. So it's not really surprising that the terminal echoes what you "type".

To automate a command execution, do not use the shell terminal. Use SSH "exec" channel. In Paramiko that is [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command).

See [Python Paramiko - Run command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9470584/850848)