# Paramiko equivalent of ssh host -t bash

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

In my Python3 script, I am trying to use Paramiko to ssh into remote devices. I can do that just fine. The issue is that `ssh` dumps me into a proprietary shell. I need to add `-t bash` to the `.connect` command to dump me into a bash shell. Here is what I have that is working:

```
ssh_tranfer = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_transfer.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)

ssh.connect(hostname=device, port=22, username=username, key_filename=private_key_name)
```

With this I can connect just fine, but like I said, I am in the proprietary shell and can't pass it commands. I am not even sure that I can do it this way.

I define all the parameters that I am using (ie - device, username, and the private key) prior to the `ssh.connect` shown above.

If I was to ssh into the device directly from my computer to go straight to the bash shell, I would use:

```
ssh username@device.com -t bash
```

I would like to find a way to do this using paramiko.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The `-t` + `bash` in `ssh` do two things:

- Starts command `bash` in "exec" channel (instead of starting "shell" channel, what `ssh` does by default).
  For that, see [Python Paramiko - Run command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9470584/850848)
- The `-t` forces an interactive session, what would be the default for "shell", but is by default disabled for "exec".
  For that, pass `get_pty=True` to [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command).

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` this way – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.