# ssh to linux server using the python

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to ssh to a Linux server using the below script. The script did not give any error but it doesn't give any result of COMMAND as well.

```py
import subprocess
import sys


HOST = "IP ADDRESS"
COMMAND = "ifconfig"


def passwordless_ssh(HOST):
    ssh = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
        shell=False,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
    if result == []:
        error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
        print >> sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
        return "error"
    else:
        return result
```

Comment: Have you successfully run this ssh command outside of Python? What errors did you get when you ran your Python program?

Comment: Please show how your ran the program, and the complete output.

Comment: Is this just part of the script? It doesn't appear that you ever call the function that is defined. In its current form it does nothing at all.

Comment: I usually use Paramiko for handling SSH tasks in Python. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470642/2224559

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @andy lester Yes the ssh to the machine works without the program

Comment: @ Blake Ottinger Yes but in my case i cannot connect to internet and import Paramiko as we have some restrictions

Comment: @ JNevill This is the only code and yeah i agree that i am not calling this def but not sure how can i call this function to get a ssh login via program